# Who is this blue skinned character?

Tags: star-wars, character-identification, revenge-of-the-sith

Whilst I was watching Episode III of the Star Wars saga, I saw this scene:

[image: Episode 3 screen capture]

To our right of Palpatine there is what appears to be a Twi'lek (opposite [Om Free taa](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Orn_Free_Taa)).

It's possible she's not a Twi'lek, but either way I was wondering if she was important enough to be named (as most characters are in Star Wars) and if so, what it was?

Comment: What makes you think she's twi'lek?

Comment: @kevin She's Blue, has her Lekku covered up.

Comment: @Pureferret Twi'leks aren't all blue, and not all Twi'leks are blue.

Comment: But some twi'leks are...? I dunno, I know OFT has aides and just I drew one two many conclusions.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

She's Pantoran, from Wroona. Her name is [Chi Eekway Papanoida](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Chi_Eekway_Papanoida) and is played by George Lucas' daughter Katie.

She has been mistaken as Twi'lek before (from Wookieepedia):

> As recently as June 2008, Papanoida's species was given as Twi'lek on the StarWars.com Databank. An exclusive action figure produced in 2006 also depicts and labels her as a Twi'lek, though this is no longer canon.

Her character also appear in the latest [Clone Wars](https://www.starwars.com/tv-shows/clone-wars/sphere-of-influence) series.

Comment: @Pureferret - I was looking through the script. Nice addition of the mistaken race too. I was just going to add that myself. It appears her race changed (or was actualized) during the course of the Clone Wars series.

Comment: IIRC this scene is in Episode 3 after Obi-wan and Anakin have returned the rescued Chancellor from General Grievous and Count Dooku on Corruscant.