# Why was Chi Eekway Papanoida called a Twi'lek?

Tags: star-wars, behind-the-scenes

I made this mistake in my other [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/13138/3804) about the [Pantoran senator](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Chi_Eekway_Papanoida) Chi Eekway Papanoida, and it also occured on the officially licensed figurine.

> As recently as June 2008, Papanoida's species was given as Twi'lek on the StarWars.com Databank.[3] An exclusive action figure produced in 2006 also depicts and labels her as a Twi'lek, though this is no longer canon.

But I'd have thought that George Lucas wouldn't forget what species his daughter was playing, *especially* when he played her father. Nor would the people making her figurine (or at least they be reliably informed from someone higher up) where the mistake was first made.

Was her species **changed** later on to fit with Lucus' character, or was this an honest **mistake** and she was always intended to be Pantoran?

Comment: Much better thank you.

Comment: @Chad Glad it could be improved!

Comment: I don't have any proof, but it also could have been a production error, given that Katie Lucas had played a Twi'lek in the previous film.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because I think she was originally intended to be based on her Starwars.com archived entry as well as her action figure.

I believe her backstory and origination changed to maintain familial continuity as the backstory between Chi Eekway and Baron Papanoida fleshed out in *Clone Wars*.

[Baron N. Papanoida](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Papanoida), whom we discover in Chi's (alleged?) father in *Clone Wars*, was played in Episode III by George Lucas. Given real life father and daughter relationship, he may have wanted to maintain that through the backstory rather than what appeared in a brief scene (which could have been crafted rapidly to insert George into his franchise in the last foreseeable movie opportunity).

According [one draft of the Revenge of the Sith](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Revenge-of-the-Sith.html), Chi Eekway is only identified by that name, without the last name "Papanoida" by which [she now appears](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Chi_Eekway_Papanoida). Her [action figure](http://www.rebelscum.com/TSClucascollectorset.asp) also identifies her without the surname.

I submit to you that the real life relationship influenced the change in relationship between the Baron N. Papanoida and Chi Eekway to father/daughter in *Clone Wars* for somewhat sentimental reasons and, given the Baron's obvious lack of leku and presence of facial hair (have we ever seen a Twi'lek with facial hair?) his race couldn't be adjusted (or make sense) so she would have to be the one to change (despite her, perhaps unpopular, action figure).

Comment: That's very well reasoned!

Comment: That is an awesome catch on the action figure.  I did add a link to a view with the robe off defiantly showing the leeku.